# Explanation of the ending of "It Follows"

Tags: ending, it-follows

The ending scene of It Follows seems pointless to me.

Jay and Paul walk down the street holding hands, and someone (I guess, the demon) follows them.

Did I miss something?

Comment: According to [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org) this movie suffers from both [Ambiguous Ending](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AmbiguousEnding) as well as [The End...Or Is It?](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheEndOrIsIt)   .... and I agree, it does (both).

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36813/ending-of-it-follows-2014

Comment: Related meta discussion: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2001/49.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick ending was discussed in an [interview in Vulture](http://www.vulture.com/2015/03/it-follows-director-the-spoiler-interview.html) with the Director; David Robert Mitchell. Although he seems to have intended to leave it ambiguous, the general [concensus among critics](http://geektyrant.com/news/the-ending-of-the-horror-film-it-follows-explained-by-director) is that it was pretty heavy-handed:

> Q. **The movie ends with Jay and Paul walking home. A ways behind them, we see a teenage boy walking in the same direction ... it might be the
>   monster, or it might not. Was that always the final shot?**
>
> A. *Yes, for sure. We had a couple variations on it — I think we had some where he was really far back, and then some where no one would ever
>   miss him  — but **we settled on the one where he’s there, but not too
>   close. It allows people to make up their own mind of what it means.***

Answer (score 1):

My guess is its Jeff as a Demon. I think he had the same haircut, beard and clothing. As you remember it always appeared as known people to the cursed ones.